# SQL funky aggregations, seeking assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the following scenario

| System | Subsystem & Filename | File Load Start Time | File Load End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | A1 transactiontxt | 2022-06-19 08:00:00 | 2022-06-19 08:00:02 |
| Alpha | A2 userscsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:02 | 2022-06-19 08:00:05 |
| Alpha | A2 employeescsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:05 | 2022-06-19 08:00:08 |
| Alpha | A1 managerscsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:00 | 2022-06-19 08:00:02 |
| Alpha | A3 customerscsv | 2022-06-19 08:00:01 | 2022-06-19 08:00:04 |
| Gamma | A1 transactiontxt | 2022-06-19 10:00:48 | 2022-06-19 10:00:53 |
| Gamma | A2 userscsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:53 | 2022-06-19 10:00:54 |
| Gamma | A2 employeescsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:27 | 2022-06-19 10:00:30 |
| Gamma | A1 managerscsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:11 | 2022-06-19 10:00:17 |
| Gamma | A3 customerscsv | 2022-06-19 10:00:13 | 2022-06-19 10:00:14 |

I want to be able to group the summary statistics by System. The info needed is when the overall started (earliest time), when it ended (latest time), and the time it took for each subsystem to occur, in seconds. From the example above, the result should look as below:

| System | Overall System Load Start Time | Overall System Load End Time | A1 Time Taken | A2 Time Taken | A3 Time Taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 2022-06-19 08:00:00 | 2022-06-19 08:00:08 | 00:00:02 | 00:00:06 | 00:00:03 |
| Gamma | 2022-06-19 10:00:11 | 2022-06-19 10:00:54 | 00:00:11 | 00:00:04 | 00:00:01 |

I cannot find a way to do this in a query, I'm trying to do select subqueries in the select clause for each column, and at the end group by only System. But this is not possible because I'd have to use an aggregate function which is not being supported with case statements in subqueries in the select clause

My approach was something like

```
SELECT System, 
min(StartTime) as 'File Load Start Time',
max(EndTime) as 'File Load End Time', 
CASE WHEN SubSystem LIKE 'A1%' THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(s, min(StartTime), max(EndTime))) Else 0 END AS 'A1 Time Taken',
CASE WHEN SubSystem LIKE 'A2%' THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(s, min(StartTime), max(EndTime))) Else 0 END AS 'A2 Time Taken',
CASE WHEN SubSystem LIKE 'A3%' THEN SUM(DATEDIFF(s, min(StartTime), max(EndTime))) Else 0 END AS 'A3 Time Taken'
FROM TABLE GROUP BY SYSTEM
```

But this does not work because the case statements need to be in a group by clause as well, and I cannot aggregate them. Sum will not work because if the same exact time is used for two subsystems, I don't want it to be summed -- they were done at the same time.

Comment: can you share the dbms you're currently working with?

Comment: @lemon sql management studio

Comment: Help others help you. Provide your test data in an easily consumed manner - as requested in many of your other questions. A script containing DDL and sample data as inserts or a fiddle will do much. If you have / must support any number of subsystems, then conditional aggregation cannot be used as a shortcut to a pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregation function cannot be employed inside another aggregation function `SUM(... MIN(...), MAX(...))`. In order to simplify your query, you need to split the operations you carry out in:

- detecting unique rows of your data
- extracting the value of "*Subsystem*" from "*Subsystem & Filename*"
- pivoting on the "*Subsystem*"
- aggregating on your relevant fields

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [System],
                    LEFT([Subsystem & Filename], 
                         CHARINDEX(' ', [Subsystem & Filename])-1) AS [Subsystem],
                    [File Load Start Time]                         AS [StartTime],
                    [File Load End Time]                           AS [EndTime]
    FROM tab
)   
SELECT [System],
       MIN([StartTime])        AS [Overall System Load Start Time],
       MAX([EndTime])          AS [Overall System Load End Time],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Subsystem]='A1' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(s, [StartTime], [EndTime]) END) AS [A1 Time Taken],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Subsystem]='A2' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(s, [StartTime], [EndTime]) END) AS [A2 Time Taken],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Subsystem]='A3' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(s, [StartTime], [EndTime]) END) AS [A3 Time Taken]
FROM cte
GROUP BY [System]
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c4b1747697b80fad2311e642ac630290).

Comment: Off course an aggregate function can be employed into another one, but you need to use a window for the outside aggregate

Comment: A window function is not an aggregate function. The difference between the two is that the former computes a value taking into account a window of values while the latter one aggregates rows. They're two completely different concepts even though they may have the same name (e.g. `SUM`, `AVG`, `COUNT`, but not `RANK`, `ROW_NUMBER`, etc...).